# JavaScript : Optimal solution to filtered out the objects from an array based on the n-level nested property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

**Requirement:** Is there any optimal or easy way to filtered out the objects from an array which contains a specific property based on its value without *recursion*.

**Problem statement:** We can achieve this requirement using recursion but as data set (array of objects) is very large and each object contains `n` number of nested objects, Recursion approach is causing performance issue.

Here is the sample mock data:

```
[{
  children: [{
    children: [{
      children: [],
      isWorking: 'yes'
    }]
  }]
}, {
  children: [],
  isWorking: 'no'
}, {
  children: [{
    children: [{
      children: [],
      isWorking: 'no'
    }]
  }]
}, {
  children: [{
    children: [],
    isWorking: 'yes'
  }]
}, ...]
```

- I want to filter out the root objects from an array which contains nested `isWorking` property with the value as `yes`.
- `isWorking` property will only available for the objects which does not contains children. i.e. `children: []`

As I said earlier, I am able to achieve this by recursion but looking for a optimal solution which will not impact the performance.

This is what I tried (Working solution):

```js
const parent = [{
  children: [{
    children: [{
      children: [],
      isWorking: 'yes'
    }]
  }]
}, {
  children: [],
  isWorking: 'no'
}, {
  children: [{
    children: [{
      children: [],
      isWorking: 'no'
    }]
  }]
}, {
  children: [{
    children: [],
    isWorking: 'yes'
  }]
}];

const isWorkingFlagArr = [];

function checkForOccupation(arr) {
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    (!obj.children.length) ? isWorkingFlagArr.push(obj.isWorking === 'yes') : checkForOccupation(obj.children)
  })
}

checkForOccupation(parent);

const res = parent.filter((obj, index) => isWorkingFlagArr[index]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Is the "performance issue" that you are blowing the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following puts each recursive call on a new microtask, thereby avoiding blowing the stack.

This code runs the same algorithm as yours but ensures that recursive calls are made asynchronously on new microtasks.

In the following code

> i.  Top-level async is not supported by StackOverflow.
>
> ii. async to enable use of await.
>
> iii. Async IIFE.
>
> iv. Your algorithm.
>
> v. Suspend continuation of the `for..of` loop until the promise
> returned by the recursive call is resolved. Akin to a `.then(() => checkForOccupation(children))`, meaning that the recursive call occurs
> with a fresh stack on a microtask, thereby mitigating the problem of a deeply nested
> recursive call and the lack of tail-call recursion optimization in JS.
> This brings with it a performance penalty.
>
> vi. Invoke the async IIFE to kick things off.
>
> vii. Invoke the outer async IIFE to compensate for the lack of
> top-level async support by StackOverflow.

```js
(async () => {  // i.
  const getFlags = async (arr) => {  // ii.
      const flags = []

      await (async function checkForOccupation(arr) {  // iii.
          for(const { children, isWorking } of arr) {  // iv.
              !children.length
                  ? flags.push(isWorking === 'yes') 
                  : await checkForOccupation(children)  // v.
          }
      })(arr)  // vi.

      return flags
  }

  const data = [{
    children: [{
      children: [{
        children: [],
        isWorking: 'yes'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    children: [],
    isWorking: 'no'
  }, {
    children: [{
      children: [{
        children: [],
        isWorking: 'no'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    children: [{
      children: [],
      isWorking: 'yes'
    }]
  }]

  const flags = await getFlags(data)
  console.log(data.filter((_, index) => flags[index]))
})()
```

The alternative approach would be to manage a stack of state explicitly, which would be a chore.

Comment: Your solution looks interesting and also it's much faster as compare to the solution I provided in question. Can you please explain it little more. Means the steps you performed in the above code snippet for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you @BenAston for the detailed description of the solution. Here is the jsbench link of the solutions https://jsbench.me/zklageluav/1 and your's is doing great. Thanks!

Comment: A better test would include representative data!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will perform better or worse than your code, but I find it significantly simpler:

```js
const checkForOccupation = (xs) => xs .flatMap (
  (x, _, __, kids = checkForOccupation (x .children || [])) => 
    x .isWorking == 'yes' || kids .length > 0  ? [{...x, children: kids}] : []
)

const data = [{children: [{children: [{children: [{children: [], isWorking: 'no'}], isWorking: 'yes'}]}]}, {children: [], isWorking: 'no'}, {children: [{children: [{children: [], isWorking: 'no'}]}]}, {children: [{children: [], isWorking: 'yes'}]}]

console .log (checkForOccupation (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We use `flatMap` to transform and filter in a single go.  We first recur on the `children` array of our node (which will bottom out when that array is empty) and check whether the returned array has any members, or if our node has the magic `isWorking` value.  If so, we return to `flatMap` an array containing a single object that has our own properties, with `children` replaced by the result of that recursive call.  If it doesn't have that value or any children, we return to `flatMap` an empty array.  `flatMap` then flattens out the collection of returned arrays.

Ben Aston -- in a comment to the question and in his own answer -- worried about blowing the stack.  As far as I can tell, this can only happen if you have an object *nested* several thousand layers deep.  If you do, I think this is likely the least of your problems.

Comment: A deeply nested object appears to be precisely the motivation for this question.

Comment: @BenAston: It's possible, of course.  But in my experience, objects nested more than ten thousand levels deep are almost always a sign of either cyclic structures -- which need a different sort of handling -- or of ill-considered design.

Comment: Best confirm with the OP tbh. Everything else is speculation. It is possible that OP is confronted with a legacy system that has a design defect and he needs to work around it. I agree: sounds bad but the question wasn't "is my system design any good?"

Comment: @BenAston: We're both only providing options.  I have no idea what "recursion approach is causing performance issue" means here.  It might be, as you guess, an extremely deeply nested object.  But it could be all sorts of other things; and it might or might not even relate to the code provided.  The OP asked for an optimal solution, but without knowing the full shape of the data, we have to guess.  I provided what I think is simpler code.  Perhaps it will improve the OP's performance to an acceptable level, perhaps not.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for this discussion and sorry for late reply. I was looking for a optimal solution in terms of performance as lot of recursive calls make the overall process slow and taking so much time for n number of nested objects. Hence, after looking into your solution it is not performance effective and taking more time to execute as compare to my and Ben's solution. here is the jsbench link : https://jsbench.me/zklageluav/1

Comment: @RohìtJíndal: There's no particular expectation for timeliness in replies; don't worry about that.  I am not even slightly tied to this solution, just offering options.  One thing, though, when doing a perf test like this, you probably want to be doing it with something more like your actual data.  I'm not saying that it would change the results in this case, but sometimes it does; a too-small sample tells you too little.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal: Also notice the difference in output.  Mine assumes you want the whole tree filtered.  If you set, say, `parent [2] .children [0] .children [1]` to the value `{"children": [], "isWorking": "yes"}`, you will see how mine differs from you original and Bens's solutions.  It may be a misreading on my part, but here we filter the tree down to the leaves with "yes" and the branches that contain them.  If that's not what you want, then this solution is definitely not for you!